# Javascript - string.replace() not replacing ALL

Tags: javascript

I'm using this to insert some string data:

```
$("#edit_order #"+key).val(value.replace('+',' '));
```

However, the second instance of "+" is not being replaced with this string:

```
123123123+APT+123
```

Instead I get the output:

```
123123123 APT+123
```

Comment: To replace all, you value "to replace" must be defined as a regular expression ... `/\+/g`

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
value.replace(/\+/g, ' ')
```

`g` is a global match flag and will cause your replace to match all instances of `+`.

Comment: Good that you figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try ...

```
$("#edit_order #"+key).val(value.replace(/\+/g,' '));
```

To replace all, your value "to replace" must be defined as a regular expression.

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/hk2qrq4u/)**